# Trouble with ScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, tableview

I have a trouble  with `scrollViewWillEndDragging`. In my **TableView** I put at the end the code:

```
extension FeedTableViewController: RefreshViewDelegate 
{
  func refreshViewDidRefresh(refreshView: RefreshView) 
  {
    delayBySeconds(3) {
        self.refreshView.endRefreshing()
     }
   }
}
```

but the problem is that the animation doesn't stop...

My github repository is this if someone very kind can help me:
https://github.com/Rosin355/PadovaNews2

The image of the tableview you see the cat animation but should stop and bring the normal tableviewcell but in my case doesn't and keep fly...

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot if someone can help me...Asked even to the DTS apple but they didn't answer...

Cheers

Romesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set RefreshView delegate? 
Since you wrote this extension `extension FeedTableViewController: RefreshViewDelegate` try this `refreshView.delagate = self` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hi Raka...thanks for the answer... Yes I did... Can you help me please? this is my git repository: https://github.com/Rosin355/PadovaNews2  se the project called "sagraPadovana" you find all the file and the one with the "extension method" is on FeedTableViewController. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RomeshSinghabahu Just downloaded you code and there is no delegate set to you RefreshView. Try add `refreshView.delagate = self` on `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Yes  it works... Very thanks man... I open a ticket to the DTS apple support and they told me to look at the documentation...If they just told me to add the delegate I save lot of time... Very thanks again God bless You...

Comment: Can I @Raka one more question? Why does this function not working? >func animateTable